# Calculating thevenin voltage with two voltage supplies

Tags: thevenin

[image: Circuit]

I can't seem to find out how to get the thevenin voltage with two parallell voltage sources. I have calculated thevenin resistance to be 2.67Ω. It is my understanding that I need to calculate the voltage between A and B. Could someone please help me out with this one.

Comment: If you remove RL, can you calc the current and voltage drop to A.

Comment: Look at this thread, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478742/finding-node-voltage/478750#478750