# Determine the voltage across the 5.0-Ω resistor in the drawing

Tags: voltage, homework

[image]

I have tried to solve this problem but I haven't seen a dc circuit with a battery on the shared portion so I don't know how to include the 2.0 volt battery in the circuit rules. Please help

Comment: what is `shared portion`?

Comment: the portion of the circuit that is part of both loops

Comment: You could look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/478752/38098), where I provide a general solution for problems like this. Once you solve the voltage at the shared node, the rest is easy.

Comment: so the answer is 0.75V

Comment: @PamelaOsborne Yes, that's the answer. Sorry about the belated confirmation, but relayman had to get my attention. Best wishes and my apologies about not confirming your answer on a timely basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use superposition.

Replace each pair of voltage sources in turn, leaving one, with a short and calculate the voltage at the T-junction for each, then add all three voltages.

So you'd be adding the voltage due to the 10V battery, the voltage due to the 2V battery and the voltage due to the 15V battery to get the total.

The difference between that and the other side of the 5\$\Omega\$ resistor is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to find the Thevinin equivalent for the circuit to the right of the 5 ohm resistor.  You will get a resistor in series with a voltage source. Then combine that with the circuit on the left.  It will be simple to solve since everything is in series.

Comment: I'm only in first year non-calculus physics class. Can you offer a simpler suggestion?

Comment: or a process to follow for a solution?

Comment: so the answer is 0.75V

Answer (score 0):

If you are studying circuits you look in you text book or online how to solve circuits like this with loop mesh equations. Very easy with just two loops like this circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Several good approaches in the other answers.  I just want to show you how to write loop equations to solve this.

First, assign loop currents like i show below:

[image]

Next, write KVL for each of the loops.  The only "trick" is to recognize their are two contributions to the voltage drop across the middle 10 ohm resistor (from both i1 and i2).

Left loop first,
$$-10 + 5i_1 + 10i_1-10i_2+2 = 0$$

Right loop next,
$$-2 + 10i_2-10i_1+10i_2+15 = 0   $$

Now, you have 2 equations in 2 unknowns and can solve.  In your case, i1 will be the actual current through the 5Ω resistor (from that you can easily calculate the voltage drop across the resistor).  If you wanted to find the current through the middle 10Ω resistor it would the ix I show below:

[image]

Where,
$$i_x=i_1-i_2$$